# How to start with Jenkins' release & deployment automation with the Pipeline plugin?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment, jenkins-pipeline

I only have experience to do build with Jenkins, and deployment was via UrbanCode. Now if I want to use Jenkins for release and deployment automation to replace UrbanCode, where shall I start? I see workflow, pipeline, etc., don't know what's the exact solution from Jenkins for the deployment automation.

After spend a day and two, I am still struggling, this time is with so many different plugins. Don't know exactly what are the plugins should be used, e.g. what's the relationship between this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin and this:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin? I am desperately looking for an well organised document on how to use Pipeline plugin to build a complete build and deployment automation solution.

Comment: A quick search revealed [this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21664334) amongst others.

Comment: @StefanHanke, I want to get rid of UrbanCode, replace with Jenkins' build-in functionalities for release and deployment automation.

Comment: Sorry, I've somehow managed to skip that piece of information...

Comment: hey have you seen this [docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/)?

Comment: and this one is focused on [syntax](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md).

Comment: Yes, https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/ only tells how to use the new https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin. But to a new comer, there are so many other plugins, and approaches.

Comment: Has anyone manage to replace UCD with Jenkins' pipeline?